# Spring boot Cacheable annotation -- how refresh results on every request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I have a spring boot application, which makes a large number of requests to external web services. I'm using the `@Cacheable` annotation in many places to cache requests. I'm trying to figure out how to cache requests on a "per-request" basis. i.e:

Suppose I have the following method which calls an external service:

```java
@Cacheable
private List<Product> listProducts(String orgCode, String channel, String userToken) {
  return externalService.listProducts(orgCode, channel, userToken);
}
```

When a request comes in to my spring application, it calls the `listProducts` method 5 times. The external service is only called once, and the cached result is used for the other 4 calls.

Now another request comes in, and calls `listProducts` again. The previously cached result is returned. However because this is a new request to my application, I want to refresh the results.

I feel like `@Cacheable` has a parameter for this that I'm just not finding.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to create a web Filter to clear your cache. Look at  `@CacheEvict(allEntries=true)`, you can annotate another method and call it in the Filter.

The filter could look like this:

```
@Component
public class CacheEvictFilter implements Filter {

    private final MyService myService;

    public CacheEvictFilter(final MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, 
      FilterChain chain
    ) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        myService.evictProducts();
    }

    // other methods
}
```

The `evictProducts` method could look like this:

```
@CacheEvict(allEntries=true)
public void evictProducts() {
    log.info("Evicted all products")
}
```